Next.js 14: How to implement a shared Singleton class across browser tabs?
I'm developing a Next.js 14 application and need to implement a Singleton class that can be shared across multiple browser tabs. This class should persist its state even when the user navigates away from the page or closes and reopens a tab. The main reason is to avoid fetching all the data (that will be in this Singleton) every time a refresh or tab opening occurs, ensuring tab synchronization.
I've attempted to use a basic JavaScript class with Object.freeze as shown below:
class Singleton {
  value = [];
  constructor() {}

  addPost = (data) => {
    this.value.push(data);
  };
}

const instance = new Singleton();
Object.freeze(instance);

export default instance;

On root layout:
import singleton from "@/class/Singleton";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  console.log("singleton: ", singleton);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

However, the instance is reinitialized every time the page is reloaded or a new tab is opened. I cannot store this information locally in the browser and need to keep it in some shared memory location instead.

Browsers do not have such memory hierarchies. There are just too many edge cases to catch for example; what happens when all tabs are closed?

You can utilise fetch caching, and maybe even put the data in local storage?
